# Django CSS relative paths not working in Amazon S3

Tags: css, django, amazon-s3

Basically I'm using S3 for my static files for a website. Most of the images are referenced in the templates but I notice that every single referenced image or file (fonts in particular) are not working.

I've made all the files public in S3 and can access them with the public links.

This is my setting.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app/static'),
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ''
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'abc-bucket'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.storage_backends.MediaStorage'
```

I've remove the AWS access and secret keys for this post.

The fonts.css contains the following;

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'rt-icons-2';
    src:url('../../fonts/rt-icons-23dab.eot?wz19bt');
    src:url('../../fonts/rt-icons-2d41d.eot?#iefixwz19bt') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../../fonts/rt-icons-23dab.ttf?wz19bt') format('truetype'),
        url('../../fonts/rt-icons-23dab.woff?wz19bt') format('woff'),
        url('../../fonts/rt-icons-23dab.svg?wz19bt#rt-icons-2') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and the AWS folder structure is;

```
 static
 - content
   - css 
     - fonts.css
 - fonts
   - rt-icons-23dab.eot
   - rt-icons-2d41d.eot
   - rt-icons-23dab.ttf
   - rt-icons-23dab.woff
   - rt-icons-23dab.svg
```

I know the CSS is working as all the styling is fine so the fonts.css is being accessed ok but the relative paths are broken and all the font icons are missing. These were working fine before I ran collectstatic and moved them to S3.

Comment: did you do a `collectstatic`? do you have any static file in this path `app/static`?

Comment: Hi, yes to both. I’ve even tried putting the full public S3 link in and it still doesn’t work. The files are definitely public because I can click on the files and see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ub8zug/serving-web-fonts-via-aws-s3-and-cloudfront). The CORS configuration was the problem.